# "Transforming" Sensor Data with Apache Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have an OPC source that generates sensor data and I need to "transform" the data.

the sensor data is stored in a csv file and looks like this:

```
Sensor    Value  Timestamp
Sensor 1  1234   XYZ
Sensor 2  1342   XYZ+1
Sensor 3  ...
...
Sensor 1  1434   XYZ+n
Sensor 2  1523   XYZ+n+1
Sensor 3  ...
...
```

The context of the data is in a factory, everytime a production has finished, a new product gets in the factory line and the sensor starts again

The destination structure should be like this

```
Product   Sensor 1  Sensor 2  Sensor  ...
X         1234      1342      ...
X+1       1434      1523      ...
...
```

I am a beginner with Apache Spark in Java and have no clue how to transform this data.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

**Update**

As mentioned, in the source data, there is no link to a specific product. In the destination data, there is no timestamp.

My idea was to aggregate the data. Everytime Sensor 1 has a Value, it is a new Product. This means that with Timestamp and Sensorname, you can get the product.

But I'm really off getting this into code. If you have any ideas on that, I would be really happy!

Comment: Using Apache Spark with Java to get things clear, sorry I forgot.

Comment: I also read this but I dont know how to fit that on the above given data... May you can help me with that?

Comment: Your first csv don't contain "product" while the excepted csv do not contain timestamp.

Comment: @Hades, I updated my question since this seems to be the show breaker.

Comment: I have an answer for you see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer by myself:

I added a new column that breaks down to a specific Product and then:

```
Dataset <Row> df = oldf
                        .groupBy("Product")
                        .pivot("Sensor")
                        .agg(functions.first(oldf.col("Value")))
```

Very happy with that!